# Is anyone using Python for GS1 XML and AS2 EDI?

Tags: python, edi

I'm helping some manufacturing companies link up their EDI systems using the GS1 XML specs (this is an international spec for companies to pass things like purchase-orders, invoices, barcodes etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1).

There are lots of Big Iron solutions, and lots of Java and C# solutions, and even a couple in PHP. But I haven't found any projects in Python.

Have you tried this, and can you offer any war stories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked with GS1 XML specs.
Nothing special, just very baroque.
for edi I use bots (http://bots.sourceforge.net)
for AS2 (bots does not do AS2) http://opensource.mendelson-e-c.com/

Comment: My e-mail alert was not fast enough... I wanted to recommend you/bots to Jagu ;-)

Comment: Thanks that looks like a really interesting gateway.

Comment: I went with your suggestion, and it worked out very well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8335522/797945

Answer (score 5):

Followup.

I made the original post back in September. It's now December and the system is complete.

In the end I did use the BOTS EDI open source project (http://bots.sourceforge.net). This is a Python platform for doing electronic data interchange translations and comms.

This turned out to be an excellent option. The development was smooth and it saved an enormous amount of work that I was expecting. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Any possiblility you have a copy of the wiki or some kind of documentation? All documentation seems to have disappeared...https://code.google.com/archive/p/bots/wikis/StartIntroduction.wiki

Comment: No, sorry. That's a real worry if the project is going away. It has been a very good platform for us.

Comment: They seem to be working on it. The project itself is now on Github: github.com/eppye-bots/bots. The documentation is available at http://botsdocs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to be working for me. For a split second the page loads and you can see the contents, but after that a 404 error appears and doesn't let me do anything.

Comment: Sourceforge project has died, but there's some activity over at https://github.com/bots-edi/bots